# VBA in Excel: concatenating from previous column

Tags: excel, vba

All, I have a spreadsheet where I'm exporting a set of numbers. The spreadsheet tracks missing numbers and looks like this:

[NOTE: this spreadsheet can have 'X' number of columns so I never know the A1:XX range -- I may need to do Range.Find?]

```
A1       |B1        |C1       |D1        |E1       |F1
------------------------------------------------------------
Column 1 |Missing # |Column 2 |Missing # |Column 3 |Missing#
1        |2         |4        |5         |7        |8
2        |          |5        |6         |8        |
3        |          |6        |          |9        |
```

The VBA macro in the spreadsheet exports the numbers in the "Missing #" columns. Currently, the macro successfully exports just the numbers from the "Missing #" columns.

BUT --

What I would like to do is export the data so the missing number is prepended/concatenated with the previous (associated) column name. Like this:

```
Column 1 - 2
Column 2 - 5
Column 2 - 6
Column 3 - 8
```

Currently, it simply exports like this:

```
Missing #  Missing #  Missing#
2          5          8
           6
```

Some of the background logic: The column range is never fixed so it is always A1:??. Also, if a number from a batch is missing, it is always placed in the next column, ie, if a number in the E column is missing, it will be noted as missing in the F column, etc.

And here's what I have so far:

```
Sub FindMissing()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xRg As Range, xRgUni As Range, xFirstAddress As String, xStr As String, srcWB As Workbook
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    xStr = "Missing #"
    Set xRg = Rows(1).Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A1:Z1").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If
    xRgUni.EntireColumn.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    fName = srcWB.Path & "\Missing UPCs" & ".csv"
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        MsgBox "your missing numbers file " & vbNewLine & "has been saved!"
        .Close False
    End With
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help, not sure how I go about concatenating the previous column name or taking into account the unknown column range... thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could store the results in an array. The column name would be `cells(1,xrg.column-1)` I think.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thanks SJR!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code - `findMissing` is doing the job to collect the relevant data in an array.

```vb
Public Function findMissing(rgToCheck) As Variant

Dim arrSource As Variant
arrSource = rgToCheck.Value

Dim arrResult As Variant
ReDim arrResult(1 To (UBound(arrSource, 2) / 2) * UBound(arrSource, 1))

Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
For c = 2 To UBound(arrSource, 2) Step 2   'look into every second column
    For r = 2 To UBound(arrSource, 1)    ' look into each row
        If Trim(arrSource(r, c)) <> "" Then   
            i = i + 1
            arrResult(i) = arrSource(1, c - 1) & " - " & arrSource(r, c)
        End If
    Next
Next

If i > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To i)
    findMissing = arrResult
End If
End Function
```

You use the result of this function like this

```vb
Public Sub saveMissing()

Dim rgToCheck As Range
Set rgToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion   'adjust ActiveSheet to your needs

Dim arrMissingValues As Variant
arrMissingValues = findMissing(rgToCheck)

If IsArray(arrMissingValues) Then

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    'write array to first sheet 
     wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrMissingValues)).Value = arrMissingValues
    
    Dim fName As String
    fName = srcWB.Path & "\Missing UPCs" & ".csv"
    With wb
        .SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        MsgBox "your missing numbers file " & vbNewLine & "has been saved!"
        .Close False
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "No missing values"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ike I'm pretty lost when it comes to VBA and Excel... is there a way to have both the findMissing and saveMissing in a single macro, or do I need to essentially run two macros, one for finding and one for saving? I was trying to make this easier for the end user where they only have to click one button. Sorry for the beginner question, I need to dive deeper into the documentation.

Comment: It's just one call: call `saveMissing` like you would have called your `findMissing`- eg. from a button - it will call the function `findMissing` (see: `arrMissingValues = findMissing(rgToCheck)`

Answer (score 1):

Please, try using the next adapted code. Since yours used to deal with ranges (in a Union range), that way could not be followed. It places the necessary strings in an array and drops its content at the end. No need of optimization...

```
Sub FindMissing()
    Dim xRg As Range, xRgUni As Range, xFirstAddress As String, xStr As String, srcWB As Workbook
    Dim fName As String, countMiss As Long
    
    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    xStr = "Missing #"
    Set xRg = rows(1).Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
    countMiss = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rows(1), xStr) 'number of "Missing #" columns
    
    Dim strPref As String, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lastR As Long
    
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        strPref = xRg.Offset(, -1).Value
        lastR = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        ReDim arrFin(1 To lastR, 1 To countMiss): i = 1: k = 1
        
        For i = 1 To countMiss: arrFin(1, i) = xStr: Next: i = 2 'fill the array header
        
        lastR = cells(rows.count, xRg.Column).End(xlUp).row
        For j = 1 To lastR
            If xRg.Offset(j).Value = "" Then k = k + 1: Exit For
            arrFin(i + j - 1, k) = strPref & " - " & xRg.Offset(j).Value
        Next j
        xFirstAddress = xRg.address
        Do
            Set xRg = rows(1).FindNext(xRg)
            If xRg.address = xFirstAddress Then Exit Do
            If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
                 strPref = xRg.Offset(, -1).Value
                lastR = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
                For j = 1 To lastR
                     If xRg.Offset(j).Value = "" Then k = k + 1: Exit For
                    arrFin(i + j - 1, k) = strPref & " - " & xRg.Offset(j).Value
                Next j
            End If
        Loop While (xRg.address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If

    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin

    fName = srcWB.Path & "\Missing UPCs" & ".csv"
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .saveas fileName:=fName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        MsgBox "Your missing numbers file " & vbNewLine & "has been saved!", vbInformation, _
                      "Saving confirmation"
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: this throws a run-time error '9' for 
arrFin(i + j - 1, k) = strPref & " - " & xRg.Offset(j).Value

Comment: @Ringthane Are there more than three such 'Missing #' columns, as you show in your question?

Comment: yes, the column range is essentially A1:XX? (different every time and more than likely more than 3)

Comment: @Ringthane I will open my laptop and asapt the code. You should state this aspect in the question. The picture must  give information to have a reproductible example...

Comment: @Ringthane Please, test the adapted code. Now, it counts how many "Missing #" columns exist and `ReDim` the array according to their number. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: It still gives a subscript out of range error for line 
arrFin(i + j - 1, k) = strPref & " - " & xRg.Offset(j).Value

Comment: @Ringthane Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? I tested the above code and it works as it should. If possible, I would like to connect to your computer to see what's happening in your environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249678/discussion-between-ringthane-and-faneduru).

Comment: I closed my laptop. I will be available only tomorrow. It is late in my country...